# How to check if a given string key exists in Enum?

Tags: typescript, enums

I have an enum defined like this:

```
export enum someEnum {
    None = <any>'',
    value1 = <any>'value1',
    value2 = <any>'value2',
    value3 = <any>'value3'   
}
```

For example, I want to check "value4" key exists in an enum. I should get `false` as value4 is not defined on the enum.

I tried `if (someEnum['value4'])` but got an error:

> Element implicitly has an 'any' type because index expression is not of type 'number'.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

You could use the `in` operator:

```
if ('value4' in someEnum) {
  // ...
}
```

Comment: @Kingintheworld. I posted an example for TypeScript 3.7.2 below.

Comment: This work only with number based enums or string enums if your value is the same as key

Answer (score 17):

**For TypeScript 3.7 with a target of es2017 or higher**

```
enum EList {
  ITEM_FOO = 'fooData',
  ITEM_BAR = 'barData'
}

const lookingForKey = 'ITEM_BAR'
const lookingForValue = 'barData'

// test if `lookingForKey` exists within `EList`
console.log(Object.keys(EList).some((v) => v === lookingForKey))

// test if `lookingForValue` exists within `EList`
console.log(Object.values(EList).some((v) => v === lookingForValue))
```

Comment: How is this approach better than using the `in` operator?

Comment: @enanone, `in` operator only checks keys, so it only works with number based enums or string enums where keys are equal to values . This will work If enum keys are different from values. Here's a [ts playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYOwrgtgBAogMgSwM4BcoG8BQUoEkAqMAsgPoBiA8hVALxQDkAZgPbMAiAhih-QDTZ5CpAEIBBAEq0GAIw4AnTt3qYAvpkwBjZiCTMANsAB0e5gHMAFACICxclUtQEIWIlQBKANxQA9N6go5MGBNbV0DYzMrWQUuDgcnF2QUTx8-Rg49JGAgA) you can test it in

Comment: @ViktorZhurbin then I guess I would always use `in` whenever possible (less verbose = better), and fall back to this solution if `in` does not get the job done

Comment: @enanone I agree with your (implicit) theme "use what is appropriate" but the statement "less verbose = better" isn't always true. Often clever, terse code can be confusing to yourself and others down the line. An extreme example of that would be code golf (trying to be minimally verbose).

Answer (score 6):

Typescript enums are a little annoying because they have two sides - the atom used to name a value, and the actual value. These each have a different way to check them.

Let's use an example enum that represents actions a content blocker can take. We'll get a kebab-case value from our API but want to use a camelCase value in TS:

```js
enum ActionType {
  block = "block",
  cssDisplayNone = "css-display-none",
  ignorePreviousRules = "ignore-previous-rules"
}
```

Now if we wanted to check if it was valid to say `ActionType.cssDisplayNone` in our code, we can check that with the `in` operator. However, if we have a value from an API and we want to see if the **value** we got is an `ActionType`, that won't work!

```js
const canBlockCss = 'cssDisplayNone' in ActionType; // Returns true
const isValidAction = 'css-display-none' in ActionType; // Returns false!
```

In this case, we need to write a [type guard](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html):

```js
function isActionType(test: any): test is ActionType {
    return (Object.values(ActionType).indexOf(test) !== -1);
}

const isValidAction = isActionType('css-display-none') // Returns true
```

This has the added bonus that if you have a variable of unknown type and pass it to a type guard, the return value will be included in Typescript's understanding of the variable, allowing you to cast it at the same time as you check it.

Answer (score 4):

For string-based enums where you want to check a value against the right side of the enum, this is the most succinct that I've found:

```
Object.values(someEnum).includes('value4')
```

This requires ES2017.

Answer (score 1):

To understand how to check if a value exists in `enum`, one has to understand what it becomes after compilation. And it is nothing more than a good old JavaScript object populated by an [IIFE](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/IIFE) (Immediately Invoked Function Expression).

Let us assume you have a simple string-based `enum`:

```
enum Test {
  TEST = "test"
}
```

This is how the compiled JavaScript code looks like:

```
var Test;
(function (Test) {
    Test["TEST"] = "test";
})(Test || (Test = {}));
```

Note that the result of this is simply:

```
var Test = {
  "TEST": "test"
}
```

It means that, obviously, the [`in`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/in) operator is enough to check if a key is present in the `enum`. It also is enough in case the value is equal to the key, but only *accidentally*.

Type guard is indeed a more viable solution, but it could also be improved by:

1. Optimizing a little - a simple `for...in` loop will do, in this case, we can even omit the `hasOwnProperty` guard.
2. Making the type guard [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/generics.html) for reusability.

Note that `val` param is not simply `T`, but is a value in `T` (hence `T[keyof T]`):

```
function hasA<T>(obj : T, val: any) : val is T[keyof T] {
    
    for(const k in obj) {
        if( obj[k] === val ) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    
    return false;
};
```

[Testing](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=2&ts=4.1.2#code/KYOwrgtgBAKsDOAXKBvAUFTsCiBlGUAvFAESIKIkA0GWBxJ8A9hMIgBYCWIA5tWgF80aAGZgQAY0ScmIKOwCG8AIIAeGAD4AFEwBGAKygAuWFSgA3BQBsTCkAE8AlMYvWoneLADaAa2D2mEVgAXVRaTHCoESYAJy0JWSQoH3c5PX1ndCxs9xEtKHTfUMIS1ysoTMicrBi2MBi5RBiwYABuKqwhbK6sSNrEerkRa3g2wXa0SxioZAZmVg5uPgnOPMUVLTgkKkRHSuzEQWEpqAATIlI7exIVvKgAQnXlTYozU%20d9rFOjtASQZiswAAdFYmDx8k98ltEGZGCw2FxeCQKhV2n8AcDQeD5EpntDYVdFkiPq0gA) to make sure everything works:

```
var t = "something";

if(hasA(Test,t)) {
    t //inferred as "Test"
}

var d = "any";

if( !hasA(Test, d) ) {
    d //inferred as "string"
}

console.log( hasA( Test, "something" ) ); //true
console.log( hasA(Test, "anything") ); //false
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question, but if your use-case is simply checking strings against a (non-const) string-enum's values, then this is probably the way to go:

```js
enum Example {
  Foo = 'foo',
  Bar = 'bar',
}

const ExampleVals = Object.values<string>(Example);

const isExample = (s: string): s is Example => ExampleVals.includes(s);
```