# "in" check returns false when using String enums

Tags: javascript, typescript, enums

I'm using TypeScript, and have the following test `Enum`

```
enum Colors {
    Red = "RED",
    Green = "GREEN",
    Blue = "BLUE",
    Other = 1
}
```

Note: This enum is just for demonstration. I don't actually mix numbers and strings, but it's just easier than to write two enums just to show what's wrong.

Now, in my code, I want to check if a specific value is in the enum, however, when checking against string `Enum`s it's always false

```
'RED' in Colors // false
"RED" in Colors // false
'GREEN' in Colors // false
"GREEN" in Colors // false
1 in Colors // true
```

I checked the compiled code, and this is how it looks

```
var Colors;
(function (Colors) {
    Colors["Red"] = "RED";
    Colors["Green"] = "GREEN";
    Colors["Blue"] = "BLUE";
    Colors[Colors["Other"] = 1] = "Other";
})(Colors || (Colors = {}));
```

Isn't it quite strange that the generated code for an integer looks different than for a string?

My TypeScript version is `2.4.1` and according to [this blog](https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/docs/tips/stringEnums.html), it's available since 2.4, so I should be good to go, right?

I tried to only use one value (string/number) in the enum, but still the same errors.
How can I check if a value exists in a string based Enum?

I compile my code to ES5, but with ES6 the same problem occurs.

Comment: Why would you want to mix number/string values to begin with?

Comment: Was just an example to show that `numbers` work, but `strings` don't. I don't have them mixed. I also don't see how this is relevant?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are accessing by property value, but, instead, 
`in` operator is used to access by `property name`.

your data looks like:

```js
var Colors = {
  Red: "RED"
}
```

so you can test if the key `Red` is in `Colors`: `'Red' in Colors // true`

if you need to check if one of the keys has "RED" (all upper) as value, 
then you need to iterate over alle the object.

```js
var Colors = {
  Red: "RED"
}

function valueInColors(needed) {
  for(let k in Colors) {
    if(Colors.hasOwnProperty(k) && Colors[k] === needed) {
      return true;
    }
  }
  
  return false;
}

console.log(valueInColors('RED'))
```

> Ok, so you mean, when I'm searching for 1 in Colors it doesn't find the element with the value 1, but instead it finds the element with the key 1 in the generated array?

```js
Colors[Colors["Other"] = 1] = "Other";

// Assignment operator returns the value, so, the previous expression is like:

Colors["Other"] = 1
Colors[1] = "Other";
```

> Ah, I understand. So technically speaking, I don't even need the values? I don't need to use "Red: Red, Green: Green", I could just go with "Red, Green", etc.?

Sometimes you need, sometimes no. In this specific case I think you don't need values. You can find further info here: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/enums.html

Comment: Okay, but why does it work that way for strings, but not for integers? I can check `1 in Colors` and it returns true.

For example in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43804805/check-if-value-exists-in-enum-in-typescript

They show how to search for value, not by property name.  Same for this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40598296/how-to-check-if-a-given-string-exists-in-enum

It shows for getting a value

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Upvoted you. I'm still wondering, however, why it works different for integers.

Comment: They are not looking by value, all the example you have linked are looking by key, the thing is that `Enums` are also indexed by `int`: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/enums.html

Comment: Ok, so you mean, when I'm searching for `1 in Colors` it doesn't find the element with the value `1`, but instead it finds the element with the key `1` in the generated array?

Comment: Thanks, but what I'm not getting is why it's different for a string? Why isn't it 

`Colors[Colors["RED"] = 'Red'] = 'Red' and then I have both as the key and value?

Comment: because that is how `Enum` works, you don't need to be aware of values, you can assume as value the key itself.

Comment: Ah, I understand. So technically speaking, I don't even need the values? I don't need to use "Red: Red, Green: Green", I could just go with "Red, Green", etc.?