# Check if string is inside enum

Tags: angular, typescript, object, include

I have some enum something like this

```
export enum Types {
  advance = 'lolipo',
  test = 'testing',
  city = 'cityNumber'
}
```

And i have some check does value exist in enum

```
 const description = 'advance';
 const isProperType = Object.values(Types).includes(description);
```

The error i got is like this

**Argument of type 'string' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Types'.**

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to check if a given string exists in Enum](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40598296/how-to-check-if-a-given-string-exists-in-enum)

Answer (score 3):

When an enum is transpiled into javascript, following object will be created

```
export var Types;
(function (Types) {
    Types["advance"] = "lolipo";
    Types["test"] = "testing";
    Types["city"] = "cityNumber";
})(Types || (Types = {}));
```

Basically, it is an object with some keys. Thus, You can simply use following expression

`description in Types`

`console.log(description in Types);` prints `true`

Comment: I don't believe `description in Types` works with string enums.

Comment: Well whether you believe it or not, it works. Check it [out](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYOwrgtgBAKgngB2AZygbwFBSgQwCYBuOIAxsFALxQDkANgPa0CWC91ANFlAC4reU1eybkxABzDlxJNucAdWmyAcpABGwAE7UMAXwwYS9EMKh4UJDSxFH5+IqWDUA3AaPJGwAHQMxACjPIFlZMNqKwiCgAlE5AA)

Comment: sorry perhaps I was mistaken. For my codebase, it was giving me a "Unsafe use of expression of type 'any'" eslint error when I tried to use just "x in Types" in a guard.

Cherios!

Answer (score 0):

For me, it seems like `.includes` was having an issue, so inside your type guard you can just fall back to regular equality checks like.

```
export enum Types {
  advance = 'lolipo',
  test = 'testing',
  city = 'cityNumber'
}

function isProperType(description: unknown): description is Types {
  for (const value of Types) {
    if (description === value) {
      return true
    }
  }
  return false
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Use the expression like this -

> Object.values(ENUM).includes(ENUM.value)

Comment: I think the point was to check a `string` is a member of a string enum.